# How to set a dynamic endpoint for retrofit POST call?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I receive **(Step 1)** a soapString from a server and I would like to forward **(Step 2)** this String to another server.

```
public interface StepTwoRestAdapter {
        @Headers({"Content-Type:text/xml"})
        @POST("/services/step2/forwardSoap")
        Observable<String> order(@Body SoapString soapString);
}
```

In this case above, the afgter my.server.com which is "/webservices/step2/forwardSoap" is constant always. How can I make this part variable?

The trick here is, that the second server (for step 2) is specified in the response of the first reponse.

EDIT:
Now, I use the proposal from @Tabish Hussain

```
public interface StepTwoRestAdapter {
    @Headers({"Content-Type:text/xml"})
    @POST("/{urlPath}")
    Observable<String> order(@Body SoapString soapString, @Path("urlPath") String urlPath);
```

}

and then I call

```
 restAdapter.create(StepTwoRestAdapter.class).order(new TypedString(soapString), uriPath)
```

whereas my uriPath is "services/step2/forwardSoap"

But retrofit then calls: 
https://my.server.com/services%2Fstep2%2FforwardSoap

As you can see '/' was replaces by "%2F"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like this

```
public interface StepTwoRestAdapter {
    @Headers({"Content-Type:text/xml"})
    @POST("/services/{soapString}/forwardSoap")
    Observable<String> order(@Path("soapString") SoapString soapString);
}
```

Comment: See comment: The path "services/step2/forwardSoap"
was replaced "services%2Fstep2%2FforwardSoap"

Comment: do it as i suggest .. pass only as soapString in the path not the complete url with "/"

Comment: Yeah, did that like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125673/retrofit-path-with-multiple-segments

Answer (score 6):

Check this links, you should be able to find answer there:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-change-api-base-url-at-runtime-2

I think the easiest way is:

```
public interface StepTwoRestAdapter {
    @Headers({"Content-Type:text/xml"})
    @POST
    Observable<String> order(@Url String url, @Body SoapString soapString);
}
```

If you are using Retrofit 1 check this one:

https://medium.com/@kevintcoughlin/dynamic-endpoints-with-retrofit-a1f4229f4a8d#.7atwl0o3t

Comment: Unfortunately no Retrofit2. But soon we have to migrate, thnx.

Comment: Not providing @Url with post method.